# Find the maximum likelihood estimates of $\mu$ and $\Sigma$ in the constrained case.

Tags: matrices, statistics, maximum-likelihood

Find the maximum likelihood estimates of $\mu$ and $\Sigma$ in the constrained case.

The testing problem is:

$H_0 :\Sigma _{12}=0$ versus $H_1 :\Sigma _{12} \not= 0$

$X_1 \sim N( \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   \mu ^{(1)}  \\
   \mu ^{(2)}  \\
  \end{array} } \right],  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   \Sigma _{11} & \Sigma _{12} \\
   \Sigma _{21} & \Sigma_{22} \\
  \end{array} } \right])$

$\Sigma =\frac{1}{n}A$

Assume that the parameters $\mu$ and $\Sigma $ are unknow.

I came until $$f_X(x) =\frac{\exp\left(-\frac12(x^{(1)}-\mu ^{(1)})^T\Sigma_{11}^{-1}(x^{(1)}-\mu ^{(1)})-\frac{1}{2}(x^{(2)}-\mu ^{(2)})^T\Sigma_{22}^{-1}(x^{(2)}-\mu ^{(2)})\right)}{(2\pi)^{n/2}\sqrt{\det\Sigma_{11} \det\Sigma_{22}} } $$

Where $$S = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n(x_k - \bar{x})(x_k -\bar{x})^T =\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   S_{11} & S_{12} \\
   S_{21} & S_{22} \\
  \end{array} } \right]
\qquad \hat{\mu} =\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^nx_k =\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
    \bar{x} ^{(1)}  \\
    \bar{x}^{(2)}  \\
  \end{array} } \right]$$

Now I need to maximize $f_X(x)$ but I do not know how. Thank you for any help.

Comment: `\sum` $\ne$ `\Sigma`.

Comment: ok, thank you and sorry